# Shortcode producing headers already sent error

Tags: functions, shortcode, wp-list-pages

I've created a shortcode for a sitemap page. When I make a change on the page and click update I get a headers already sent error. Below is my shortcode and the two error messages. I'm wondering if I need to work `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` into my function but I'm not 100% positive how it should be formatted.

```
function site_map2( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'exclude' => '',
        ), $atts );
        return '<ul>' . wp_list_pages('exclude=' . $atts['exclude'] . '&sort_column=post_title&title_li=') . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode( 'SiteMap2', 'site_map2' );
```

Here are the error messages:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php:1205) in /public_html/wp-admin/post.php on line 197
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php:1205) in /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1167

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adjustment to my function below fixed the issue but I wanted to make sure that this is the right way to handle the shortcode. I've added ob_start(); and ob_get_clean(); to the function. Is this the correct way to handle something like this?

```
function site_map2( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'exclude' => '',
        ), $atts );
        ob_start();
        echo '<ul>' . wp_list_pages('echo=false' . '&exclude=' . $atts['exclude'] . '&sort_column=post_title&title_li=') . '</ul>';
        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'SiteMap2', 'site_map2' );
```

Comment: Sure. If you have to output, `ob_start() / ob_get_clean()` are what I use often.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the value from [`wp_list_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) and not ['echo'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#parameters) by default.

> 'echo'
>
> (bool) Whether or not to echo the list of pages. Default true.

```
return '<ul>' . wp_list_pages( 'echo=false' . '&exclude=' . $atts['exclude'] . '&sort_column=post_title&title_li=') . '</ul>';
```

Comment: I implemented this into my functions file but I still get the same error. I click update and I'm taken to a page that display my site map but without my template and styles "mysite.com/wp-admin/post.php" with the error messages at the bottom of the page. It's very strange.

Comment: either way you shouldn't echo output from the shortcode, only return the final string.